# Using multithreading, not able to launch multiple IE instances in webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

Working on selenium webdriver.I have to run 10 or more instances of an automated test case on IE. I tried using Grid2 with Webdriver, but the grid launches the IE instances only one after another if I am executing in the same machine.Using testNG alone(without grid)also gave the same result. To get around this, I am threading the test case and am invoking multiple threads from a driver script. This works well in Firefox, but not in IE. In case of IE if I try to invoke more than two instances( does not matter how many more), only one instance gets invoked.

Anyone faced a similar problem before? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

This is because by default the node linked to a Sel Grid 2 hub launches ONLY one 1 IE instance, while it launches 5 instances of Firefox and Chrome.

Launch your node differently with more IE instances.
You could use something like

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -port 4445 -role node -hub http://yourhub:4444/grid/register -browser browserName="internet explorer",platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=5
```

You can check the number of browser instances for each node at this URL

```
http://yourhubserver.com:4444/grid/console
```

Comment: Its better not to launch multiple IE instances in same machine. Unlike FF or chrome, IE shares all cookies and other stuffs between the instances (coz it doesn't have profile concept). So you will have a tough time finding out whether your test failed due to the sharing pbm or application pbm

Comment: I had tried adding the 'maxinstance' parameter after a brief search in the net earlier. But it didnt solve the issue. By the way if I am to open a different node, the 'maxinstance' parameter should be given before specifying the port; didnt work anyways.

Comment: @A.J- I need to launch it in the same machine cos thats how i need to test it.There is some known firefox compatability issues which i have to overlook. The current effort is focusing on IE.

Answer (score 0):

The default no of instances of IE that can be launched using Selenium Grid2 is '1' only. To run multiple instances you can do something like this :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar -role wd -browser "browserName=internet explorer,version=8,maxInstances=5,platform=WINDOWS" -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```